# c++ usigned long long range vs mysql unsigned bigint range

Tags: c++, mysql, bigint, unsigned-long-long-int, udf

I have a MySQL UDF that returns **unsigned long long** value. When i call this function in MySQL and the Data has been saved in database, MySQL returns warning:
 "**BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range**".
How can i save large unsigned long long numbers in database?

MySQL version: *5.5.43*
OS : *Ubuntu 14.04*

please help.

Comment: What is your column definition? A bigint is 8 bytes and an unsigned long long is (usually) also 8 bytes. It should fit. Also, it would help to show us the code and exactly where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `unsigned long long` data type is 64-bit, it should fit quite well into the MySQL `BIGINT UNSIGNED` type, which is also 64 bits.

I would suggest checking your C implementation `limits.h` ( or `climits` for C++) file for the macro `ULONG_MAX` to ensure it *is* only 64 bits.

---

You should be aware however that there are certain operations you can perform on an unsigned value that will also give you this error. It may not be applicable if you're simply storing the exact value returned from the UDF but, if you're doing something like:

```
select my_udf() - 22 from somewhere
```

and `my_udf()` returns `15` (for example), you'll see that error message because `-7` cannot be represented in an unsigned type.

If that is the case, the solution *may* be as simple as casting the return value to a signed type, but we would need more information on what it can return to advise correctly.

Comment: thanks paxdiablo for reply.I found out that when i create UDF in MySQL and set return type to INTEGER, the MySQL considers this type as "long long" not "unsigned long long" and this is the problem. how can i fix this?

Comment: @Ghasem, from the doco, it appears you can only do integer, real and string. You may have to return the value as a string (such as with `sprintf` in the C code) and coerce it into the correct type back in SQL.

Comment: I used casting the return value to a unsigned type and this solved my problem. thanks paxdiablo :)